# Traditional form of product

Tags: formatting

How to convert the following formula into the traditional form of product?

```
(x[1] - x[2])^2 (x[1] - x[3])^2 (x[2] - x[3])^2 (x[1] - 
   x[4])^2 (x[2] - x[4])^2 (x[3] - x[4])^2 (x[1] - x[5])^2 (x[2] - 
   x[5])^2 (x[3] - x[5])^2 (x[4] - x[5])^2
```

to

$\prod_{1 \leqslant j<i \leqslant 5}\left(x_i-x_j\right)^2$

**EDIT**

Sorry for my inaccurate description of the problem. This is a problem in the textbook:

$s_k=x_1^k+x_2^k+\cdots+x_n^k, k=0,1,2, \cdots$,

$\boldsymbol{A}=\left(a_{i j}\right)_{n \times m}$ ， and  $a_{i j}=s_{i+j-2}, i, j=1,2, \cdots, n_{\text {. }}$

To prove

$|\boldsymbol{A}|=\prod_{1 \leqslant j<i \leqslant n}\left(x_i-x_j\right)^2$

The following is the code taking the 5th order matrix as an example, but I hope to get the results in textbook form ($\prod_{1 \leqslant j<i \leqslant 5}\left(x_i-x_j\right)^2$) directly with code.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
s[k_] := Sum[x[v]^k, {v, 1, 5}];
mA[i_, j_] := s[i + j - 2];

mA = Table[mA[i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]
FullSimplify[Det[mA]]
```

> (x[1] - x[2])^2 (x[1] - x[3])^2 (x[2] - x[3])^2 (x[1] -
> x[4])^2 (x[2] - x[4])^2 (x[3] - x[4])^2 (x[1] - x[5])^2 (x[2] -
> x[5])^2 (x[3] - x[5])^2 (x[4] - x[5])^2

Comment: What do you mean by _convert_? Use `(x[1] - x[2])^2 (x[1] - x[3])^2 (x[2] - x[3])^2 (x[1] - x[4])^2 (x[2] - x[4])^2 (x[3] - x[4])^2 (x[1] - x[5])^2 (x[2] - 
   x[5])^2 (x[3] - x[5])^2 (x[4] - x[5])^2` as the input and output $\prod_{1 \leqslant j<i \leqslant 5}\left(x_i-x_j\right)^2$, or create an expression that looks like $\prod_{1 \leqslant j<i \leqslant 5}\left(x_i-x_j\right)^2$ and will evaluate to the given expression as shown by Bob in answer below?

Comment: Please take a look at my EDIT.  Thank you. @xzczd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];

Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]

expr = (x[1] - x[2])^2 (x[1] - x[3])^2 (x[2] - x[3])^2* 
     (x[1] - x[4])^2 (x[2] - x[4])^2 (x[3] - x[4])^2* 
      (x[1] - x[5])^2 (x[2] - x[5])^2 (x[3] - x[5])^2* 
      (x[4] - x[5])^2;

(expr2 = 
   Inactive[Product][(x[i] - x[j])^2, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, i - 1}]) // 
     TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
expr == expr2 // Activate // Simplify

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** More generally,

```
s[k_, n_] = Sum[x[v]^k, {v, 1, n}];

mA[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  Table[s[i + j - 2, n], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];

mAdet[n_Integer?Positive] := Det[mA[n]] // Simplify

(prod[n_] = Inactive[Product][
   (x[i] - x[j])^2, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, i - 1}]) // 
  TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
And @@ Table[mAdet[n] == prod[n] // Activate // Simplify, 
  {n, 1, 6}]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Add zero to the original expression

```
(expr3 = expr + prod[5] - Activate[prod[5]] // Simplify) //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question. What I described earlier is not accurate enough.

Comment: Thank you for your editing. In my question, I mean whether it is possible to directly add some commands to the code so that it can be directly output into the traditional form of product "expr2". At present, the code you give still needs to get this result "expr" first, and then convert it to the traditional format "expr2" by observing the expression "expr". In fact, it is semi-automatic. Maybe this requirement of mine is relatively difficult and MMA cannot achieve it. Anyway, thank you very much. @Bob Hanlon

Comment: Thank you for your EDIT 2. This is very helpful to me.